# Capturing photos of a book

Tags: copyright

I have taken a book from my university's library and it states in the second page :

> The law of March 11, 1957 authorizes only "copies or reproductions strictly reserved for the private use of the copier and not intended for collective use".
>   Any representation or reproduction, in whole or in part, made without the consent of the publisher, is unlawful.

It is a book written in french and a french address containing "Paris" figures in the same page so this is probably a french law.
Any of you have an idea on whether this law is still up or not?
This allows me to take photos I guess but I am not sure on the validity of the law as I stated in the last phrase.
[image]

Comment: I believe the law you need to concern yourself with is the law where you, and the book, are located, not where the book was published or printed. So what country are you in?

Comment: Well in my country you'll find stores where you can buy windows (cracked that is) for 0.66 USD :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the question is about what the law allows, and not what the history of that part of the 1957 law is. For the history, you can start tracing [here](https://wipolex.wipo.int/en/legislation/details/14231), looking for amendments and repeals. The currently codified law [Art. L122-5](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006069414&idArticle=LEGIARTI000006278917) has a modification of the original exception that copies ou reproductions *réalisées à partir d'une source licite et* strictement réservées à l'usage privé du copiste et non destinées à une utilisation collective", adding that the copy must come from a lawful source.